# How to add Get variable to a clean url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, seo, clean-urls

I am creating a web page using php.
Where i created a clean url by htaccess

```
techoming.com/videos
```

Now i want to add a get variable such as

```
techoming.com/videos?cat=fun
```

Please help me here

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] or samples of the code that you have attempted

Comment: what you need to look into is `$_GET`. please do some research before asking. or maybe even read the manual, as that will get you even further than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic way to make that work: add this to your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^videos/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)$ /videos.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Users will see http://www.website.com/videos/fun but your server will process that link as http://www.website.com/videos?cat=fun